# Error while starting mysql without host name

Tags: mysql

While installing MySQL I am facing following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

but when I tried with host address it actually started

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 mysql -u root -p
```

why I am not getting logged in without hostname?

Comment: Looks like the mysql Server is not running

Comment: how to resolve such problem?

Comment: start mysql deamon

Comment: It gives me error: start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused